# Queue insertion based on condition

Tags: c, queue, structure

I am trying to insert values to a queue based on a condition. Condition is the value entered previously should be larger than the value which is going to be inserted. My problem is according to my data i have been provided with, one value is small than all the other values, so other values are not inserted in to the queue.

I am stuck here the whole day, without any clue.

Here is what i have done so far :

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<malloc.h>
    #define MAX 180

    struct cakes{
      int spongecake;
      int meringue;
      int chocalate;
      int red_velvet;
      struct newcake *next;
    };

    struct Queue{
       int front;
       int rear;
       int count;
       int cake[10];
    };

    void order_out(struct cakes *); 
    void init(struct Queue *);
    int isFull(struct Queue *);
    void insert(struct Queue *,int);
    int isEmpty(struct Queue *);
    int removes(struct Queue *);

   main()
   {
      struct cakes *head;
      head=(struct cakes*)malloc(sizeof(struct cakes));
      order_out(head);
   }

   void init(struct Queue *q)
   {
        q->front=0;
        q->rear=10-1;
        q->count=0;
   }

   int isFull(struct Queue *q)
   {
        if(q->count==10)
        {
         return 1;
        }
        else 
        {
             return 0;
        }
   }

  void insert(struct Queue *q,int x)
  {
      if(!isFull(q))
      {
         q->rear=(q->rear+1)%10;
         q->cake[q->rear]=x;
         q->count++;
      }
  }

  int isEmpty(struct Queue *q)
  {
      if(q->count==0)
      {
          return 1;
      }
      else
      {
          return 0;
      }
  }

  int removes(struct Queue *q)
  {
      int caked=NULL;

      if(!isEmpty(q))
      {
          caked=q->cake[q->front];
          q->front=(q->front+1)%10;
          q->count--;
          return caked;
      }
   }

   void order_out(struct cakes *theorder)
   {
        struct Queue s;
        int k=0;
        int i=1;    
        int value1;
        int value2;

        int counter=1;
        theorder->spongecake=20;
        theorder->meringue=75;
        theorder->chocalate=40;
        theorder->red_velvet=30;


        init(&s);
        insert(&s,theorder->chocalate);

        value1=theorder->chocalate;


        for(;k<10;k++)  
        {
            if(value1>theorder->spongecake)
            {
                insert(&s,theorder->spongecake);
                value1=theorder->spongecake;
            }

            if(value1>theorder->meringue)
            {
                insert(&s,theorder->meringue);
                value1=theorder->meringue;
            }

            if(value1>theorder->red_velvet)
            {
                 insert(&s,theorder->red_velvet);
                 value1=theorder->red_velvet;
            }
        }

        while(!isEmpty(&s)) 
        {   
            printf("\n%d",removes(&s));
        }
}
```

Any idea on how to make the other values entered in to the queue but also at the same time check whether the previous value is larger than the current value.

EDIT :

I tried adding a count meaning if the count % value1==0, then i tried to make the value1 into a bigger value by multiplying by 5 but still only those 2 values got inserted.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the context? The logic looks correct but what are you expecting as result?

Comment: What happens when condition is not met? Are you going to drop that item?

Comment: the thing is with this logic the other values which are more than the sponge cake arent entered in to the queue. Only 2 values get inserted the chocalate cake value and sponge cake value.

Comment: `malloc.h` is ancient. `malloc` has lived in `stdlib.h` since the 1989 C standard.

Comment: Why does `removes()` only return a value if `!isEmpty(q)`? A non-void function not returning a value is a bug.